# How to set up chef with node from command line?

Tags: chef

So I'm installing Chef for the first time on an EC2 instance using the [quick start guide](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Cookbook+Quick+Start) and I have hit a wall at the point where I have to add a node so that running "sudo chef-client" does not give me a "401" error.

Here are the steps I've followed

```
sudo gem sources -a http://gems.opscode.com
sudo gem install ohai chef json

sudo apt-get install couchdb

sudo /etc/init.d/couchdb start
sudo /etc/init.d/couchdb status

sudo gem install chef-server chef-server-slice
sudo gem install stompserver

stompserver &

sudo vi /etc/chef/server.rb
sudo chef-indexer
sudo chef-server -c2 -N

git clone git://github.com/opscode/chef-repo.git
cd chef-repo
vi config/rake.rb
rake test
git ci -am 'Add everything'
rake install

sudo chef-client
```

I have read through the [managing nodes page](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Nodes#Nodes-ManagingNodes) but the documentation does not give me enough information to set myself up --  I have tried adding a registration token, but specifying it in /etc/chef/server.rb does not seem to change anything, and neither does sudo  chef-client -t 'token'

I cannot use a web browser on this instance (tried lynx, it doesn't seem sufficient), so anything I do has to be doable through command line.  Help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just getting started with chef you might want to [skip ahead to chef 0.8](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Upgrading+Chef+0.7.x+to+0.8.x), which is due to be released Real Soon Now. The upcoming version introduces a new key validation scheme that renders this bit of madness you're encountering obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to delete the pending registration for this client (which you can't do from the command line, so an SSH tunnel is pretty much your only option) and then you can do this:

```
echo "{ \"run_list\": [ ] }"  > nothing.json
sudo chef-client -j nothing.json -t `cat /etc/chef/validation_token`
```

Answer (score 0):

and try to use "sudo -E chef-client"...

Answer (score 0):

The installation guide for Chef is here:

- http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Installation

It has links for how to install a Chef Server, how to install Chef on client nodes or Chef Solo, and how to use Opscode's Hosted Chef as a Chef Server.

The steps outlined in the original question reflect a much older version of Chef.